# Flexbox - Equal height image columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple flexbox layout like this

```css
   html,body {
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
   }
   
   body {
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   }
   
   .panel-grid
   {
   -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
 margin-bottom:30px;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:space-between;
 }
 
 #section-163 {
 width:calc(61.8034% - ( 0.38196600790794 * 30px ) );
 align-self:auto;
 }
 
 #section-260
 {
 width:calc(38.1966% - ( 0.61803399209206 * 30px ) );
 align-self:auto;
 }
 
 .myimage {
 object-fit:cover;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="panel-grid panel-no-style">
 <div id="section-163" class="panel-grid-cell">
  <div class="rty-panel widget widget_image-widget panel-first-child panel-last-child" style="height: 100%;">
   <div class="rty-widget-image-widget rty-widget-image-widget-base" style="height: 100%;">
    <img class="myimage" src="https://dummyimage.com/1600x900/000/fff">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div id="section-260" class="panel-grid-cell">
  <div class="rty-panel widget widget_image-widget panel-first-child panel-last-child" style="height: 100%;">
   <div class="rty-widget-image-widget rty-widget-image-widget-base" style="height: 100%;">
    <img class="myimage" src="https://dummyimage.com/500x600/000/fff">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to use object-fit to get the images to crop so that the height is matched.

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `align-items: flex-start` from `.panel-grid`. It's overriding the `stretch` default.

```
 .panel-grid {
   /* -webkit-align-items: flex-start; */
   /* align-items: flex-start; */
   margin-bottom: 30px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
 }
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel-grid {
  /* -webkit-align-items: flex-start; */
  /* align-items: flex-start; */
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#section-163 {
  width: calc(61.8034% - ( 0.38196600790794 * 30px));
  align-self: auto;
}

#section-260 {
  width: calc(38.1966% - ( 0.61803399209206 * 30px));
  align-self: auto;
}

.myimage {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-grid panel-no-style">
  <div id="section-163" class="panel-grid-cell">
    <div class="rty-panel widget widget_image-widget panel-first-child panel-last-child" style="height: 100%;">
      <div class="rty-widget-image-widget rty-widget-image-widget-base" style="height: 100%;">
        <img class="myimage" src="https://dummyimage.com/1600x900/000/fff">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="section-260" class="panel-grid-cell">
    <div class="rty-panel widget widget_image-widget panel-first-child panel-last-child" style="height: 100%;">
      <div class="rty-widget-image-widget rty-widget-image-widget-base" style="height: 100%;">
        <img class="myimage" src="https://dummyimage.com/500x600/000/fff">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now.