# Equal Height Images with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a page (a catalogue of books), where the books should be displayed in rows in a flexbox container. Each book is an individual block, which contains a heading (name of the book) and the image of the book cover directly below it. I would like for all images to be equal height and fill up the whole block, but this does not seem to be working for me. Here is what the blocks look like right now:

[image: Book Catalogue]

Some research on Stack pointed to [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50932663/flexbox-equal-height-image-columns), but the proposed solutions did not seem to work, also. Why are the images different heights in the first place, even though I pass 100% height to the image element inside the container? And how can I resolve this?

Full HTML/CSS can be seen in the [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/AegisX303/o2cuwj7n/14/)

HTML:

```
<div class="flexbox">
    <div class="item">
      <h2 class="catalogue">
        <a href="items/pyramid_texts.html" target="_blank">
           Тексты пирамид
        </a>
      </h2>
      <img class="catalogue"
           src="images/pyramid_texts.png" alt="Тексты пирамид">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <h2 class="catalogue">
        <a href="items/coffin_texts.html" target="_blank">
           Тексты саркофагов
        </a>
      </h2>
      <img class="catalogue"
           src="images/coffin_texts.jpg" alt="Тексты саркофагов">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <h2 class="catalogue">
        <a href="items/book_of_the_dead.html" target="_blank">
           Египетская книга мертвых
        </a>
      </h2>
      <img class="catalogue"
           src="images/book_of_the_dead.png" alt="Книга мертвых">
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
  a
  {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  a:hover
  {
    color: red;
  }

  div.flexbox
  {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

  div.item
  {
    height: 20%;
    width: 20%;
  }

  h2
  {
    background-color: #FFF3D9;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400px;
    style: block;
    text-align: center;
  }

  img
  {
    height: 20%;
    outline: 2px solid red;
    width: 20%;
  }

  img.catalogue
  {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

**UPDATE**: Tried experimenting with `background-size: cover` and other CSS elements, but to no avail. Could it be that my HTML structure is ill suited for this task? Right now I have a parent flexbox block and each "item" block (for each book) contains a header element with the title of the book and an `<img>` element. Should I change the structure and take the header out of the item block, for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    a {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      color: red;
    }
    
    h2 {
      background-color: #FFF3D9;
      color: black;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 400;
      style: block;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    img {
      height: 20%;
      outline: 2px solid red;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    img.catalogue {
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: contain;
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .flexbox {
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .flexbox .col {
      flex: 1;
      padding: 7px;
    }
    
    .flexbox .col:nth-child(1) {
      background: #ccc;
      -webkit-order: 1;
      -ms-flex-order: 1;
      order: 1;
    }
    
    .flexbox .col:nth-child(2) {
      background: #eee;
      -webkit-order: 0;
      -ms-flex-order: 0;
      order: 0;
    }
    
    .flexbox .col:nth-child(3) {
      background: #eee;
      -webkit-order: 2;
      -ms-flex-order: 2;
      order: 2;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="flexbox">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item">
        <h2 class="catalogue">
          <a href="items/pyramid_texts.html" target="_blank">
                   Тексты пирамид
                </a>
        </h2>
        <img class="catalogue" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" alt="Тексты пирамид">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item">
        <h2 class="catalogue">
          <a href="items/coffin_texts.html" target="_blank">
                   Тексты саркофагов
                </a>
        </h2>
        <img class="catalogue" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" alt="Тексты саркофагов">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item">
        <h2 class="catalogue">
          <a href="items/book_of_the_dead.html" target="_blank">
                   Египетская книга мертвых
                </a>
        </h2>
        <img class="catalogue" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" alt="Книга мертвых">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should explain why you suggest what you suggest.

Comment: Thank you, but this did not align the image heights. The images filled the column blocks indeed, but the height discrepancy remains. If you could, please explain the -ms-flexbox and -webkit properties. Not sure how they work.